# how to get available spaces in car parking area through google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am a student and i have to make car parking Android App as my final year project.
In which the user can look for different parking Areas at his current location and can also check the availability of parking spaces in specific parking area. I don't know how i can get data of cars parked in parking area at real time. There are no sensors or satellites used to get the info. Is there Any Google API to get this info? or can we get this information through Google Maps or not? If yes, then how?
Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Android project is highly dependent on the API services available from the parking lot providers themselves. As far as I know there is no centralized API globally for parking API, and Google certainly doesn't provide this data.

As an example, you could scrape data from a live parking spaces provider (where scraping is permitted), such as [this Dublin live parking page](http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/carparks.htm)